# Advantage and disadvantage of spanning tree with even distance

Tags: algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

It's new year day and still can't solve my problem about a spanning tree algorithm. I can't insert picture yet so I have to try to explain the enviroment with words.

It's 36 nodes and the distance to every nodes is even. The question is if the distance is even, it doesn't matter which way to pass message from node with ID 1 (the root) to the last node with ID 36. Because the distance is even there's no time saving, energy saving or message saving algorithm right? I hope someone understand my question

edited:

1. Enviroment

   ```
   1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6
   |   |   |   |   |   |
   7   8   9  10  11  12
   |   |   |   |   |   |
   13  14  15  16  17  18
   |   |   |   |   |   |
   19  20  21  22  23  24
   |   |   |   |   |   |
   25  26  27  28  29  30
   |   |   |   |   |   |
   31  32  33  34  35  36
   ```

This is my choice of spanning tree. Node with ID 36 send it information thru 30,24,18,12,6,5,4,3,2,1 (one is the root) and then node 1 send information to the base station. Because it doesn't have any cost it doesn't really matter which path I choose to send the information from node 36 to node 1 because the cost will still be the same.

1. My Spanning tree Algorithm

   - When start, only the root is marked.
   - The root send search message to it neighbor
   - If a node is not marked, when it recieves search messages from other nodes:
   - it mark itself
   - Select the nodes with lowest ID as a "parent" and reply "non-parent" to the other nodes
   - If the node is already mark, it replies "non-parent"
   - If a node is already marked and recieve a parent message it marks the sender as a child
2. I can't show you guys the flowchart because I don't have the privilege to insert images.
3. Pseudo Code (haven't done it)
4. Conclusion - Here I should write down the advantage and disadvantage of my algorithm, but right now I can't think of any advantage and disadvantage

Comment: It's new year day and I still can't solve P=NP problem.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense to me - "it doesn't matter which way to pass message" - if its a spanning tree then there is only ONE way to go from node A to node B since there are no cycles.

Comment: How can the distance to every node be even? That would imply there's no adjacent nodes since they would have distance 1. There's no mention or clue about advantages or disadvantages in the question, nor about spanning trees.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, it would be easier to show a picture of my enviroment than try to explain it with words.

Comment: @TrieBui: Try starting with the basics.  What do the nodes/vertices represent?  If there is an edge between two nodes, what does that mean?  Does it have a numeric "weight" or "cost"?  Is it bidirectional?  What is your ultimate goal -- is it to find a minimum total cost to connect all the nodes to each other?  (If so then a minimum spanning tree is the right way to go.)  Is it to find a lowest-cost path from any node to any other node?  (If so then a MST will not give you the optimal answer.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker: First I just want to say thanks for not look down on me and for you help.

I got a enviroment from my teacher. He just said the distance and even and there's no "cost" or "weight". The enviroment is 6*6 in a square (hope you understand). That's why it's so hard, if he gave me some "cost" or other information. Then I can choose the path with smallest cost and I can explain, but right now I have now idea.

Comment: @TrieuBui: I'm afraid it's still difficult to understand what you're trying to accomplish.  I'm assuming there are 36 nodes, with each node (except the ones at the edges) linked to its 4 neighbours (above, below, left and right).  If no costs or weights are given, you would normally assume each edge has cost 1.  Also I take it you mean "He just said the distance *was* even".  But I'm not sure what you are being asked to find -- is it a spanning tree for the particular 36-node graph you have been given?  It almost sounds like you are being asked to prove something about this class of graphs.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: yes you got the enviroment correct. He told me to do 6 things.

1. Choose the path of the spanning tree (i'll try to explain in on my question above)
2. My algorithm
3. Flow Chart
4. Pseudo Code
5. Conclusion
6. Further thinking

I think he want me to show him my solution and why I choose to do that. etc. I'll try to write down what I have done so far.

Comment: @TrieuBui: OK those new details help but there are still some things that aren't clear.  It seems like the question is "Find a minimum spanning tree for this graph", although I'm not certain about that because I don't see how the business about "if the distance is even" fits into that question.  Also I take it that each node is in fact a CPU of some kind that can only communicate with its 4 direct neighbours, is that right?  So perhaps the goal is for these CPUs to discover a MST using only local communication?

Comment: @TrieuBui: Finally, it can't be the case that "nothing has any cost" because that renders the problem uninteresting.  As I said, if no numeric costs are given you would normally assume each edge has cost 1 rather than cost 0.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: So if the question is find the minimum spanning tree for this graph. How would you choose the spanning tree? Assume the cost is 1. No matter how you choose the information from node 1 to 36 will cost at least 10. The nodes is computer or routers.

Comment: @TrieuBui: Yes, it will cost at least 10.  But I'm not sure how you would decide which of the many possible minimum spanning trees to use -- maybe one that induces the smallest maximum distance between 2 nodes?  I.e. given an MST, there will be some pair of nodes which has maximum distance (e.g. nodes 31 and 36 are distance 15 apart in your MST); it makes sense to look for a MST for which this maximum distance is minimum.  But I'm just guessing at what the criteria are -- you should have been told what you're trying to optimise.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: I understand what you saying. Gosh this is killing me. I think he just want me to explain why I choose that kind of spanning tree. He told me there's no right or wrong in this case.

Comment: @TrieuBui: In that case I don't think I can help you sorry.  My advice would be to ask for clarification from your teacher -- maybe you could show him this conversation on SO.  Good luck!

Comment: @j_random_hacker: I think I have to talk to him. Thank for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

By "even" I think you mean "Irregardless of where I start, the distance to move one node horizontally in my diagram is always 1, and the distance to move vertically is always 6."

Your question then sounds like "Do all paths from the upper left to the lower right have the same total length?"  If we restrict our attention to paths that, at each step, always move either down or to the right, then the answer is "yes".

To see this, note we need in total to make 5 hops down, and 5 hops to the right.  Suppose we pick a path that does so (but not necessarily in that order.)  Since all downward hops have the same cost, and all rightward hops have the same cost, we can find the total cost of the path by considering each hop in order, writing a 6 for each downward hop and 1 for each rightward hop, and add the list together.

For example, the cost of path `RRDDRDRDDR` is `1 + 1 + 6 + 6 + 1 + 6 + 1 + 6 + 6 + 1`.

Now we can see something interesting.  A different path with 5 down hops and 5 right hops will have the same list of 5 `6`s and 5 `1`s, just summed in a different order.  We can now observe that addition is commutative, and conclude that these two sums must come out equal.  That is, any path moving down and to the right has the same total length (`35`) as any other.

Given that, your spanning tree is as good as any other, assuming the underlying graph really is a grid.

Comment: Actually, on second thought it seems your vertical costs are also all `1` in the diagram.  It doesn't change the proof (and distinguishing vertical from horizontal edge costs is helpful in seeing how it goes.)